# Cant get the token from request at server side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jwt

I am referring [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543) example 
I was trying to set the token on header from the front end, via $localStorage. I have verified the token at $localStorage.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function($q, $location, $localStorage) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($localStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/signin');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

At serverside I am trying to get the token, in my route middleware to authenticate.

```
    var api = express.Router();
    api.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
        next();
    });

api.use(function(req, res, next) {    
    var bearerToken;
    var bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];

     }
```

The `bearerHeader` is always getting undefined.

Comment: Have you debugged the request at client side to see if`localStorage.token` is not null and is really sent to server?

Comment: Yes, It is valid and sending to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var bearerHeader = req.headers["Authorization"];
```

Capital A instead of small A